# Permission denied when docker-compose build - Errno 13

Tags: docker, permissions, supervisord

I am trying to build simple Docker file

```
...
RUN apt install supervisor -y
....
```

But i got some error with permission. It happen only my computer, i tried in other pc (ubuntu) but only i give that error. I also did chmod 0777 for all suspected folders...

Information about versions:

**Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~23.04.1**

```
Setting up python3.11-minimal (3.11.2-6) ...
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-311.pyc.140366352578720'dpkg: error processing package python3.11-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.11-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.11-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt install supervisor -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'sms_api_site' failed to build : Build failed
```